# Program does not work (leading zeroes)

Tags: c++, formatting

You have to write an ITERATIVE procedure write_digit(d,x) that receives a digit d and a natural number x, and writes x times the digit d in the standard output (cout). For example, the call write_digit(3,5) writes 33333, whereas the call write_digit(5,3) writes 555.

I have problem with this code and it has to do with leading zeroes. Example:
write_digit(0,3) -> 000 -> My output: 0 (not a surprise)

The problem would be resolved in 1 minute if I was allowed to use iomanip

```
if (d == 0) cout << setw(x) << setfill('0') << "";
```

However, I CAN ONLY USE iostream and string.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void write_digit(int d,int x) {
    int original_d = d; 
    for (int i = 1; i < x; ++i) d = d*10 + original_d;
    if (x == 0) cout << "";
    else cout << d;
}

int main () {
    int d,x;
    cin >> d >> x;
    write_digit(d,x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely overcomplicating the assignment, just make a simple loop without any edge conditions, it will work for any number, even for non-digits.

```
void write_digit(int d, int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) // Loop x times
        std::cout << d;         // Output digit
    std::cout << '\n';          // Output newline
}
```

Comment: Completely forgot about this possibility, dumb me.